# How to get the second value in list object using thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm sending a model attribute object(product) from my controller to th:each tag in view page.

If that object contains 3 values like 0,1,3, I can get by using 
   `th:each="var:${product}"`
and then 
   `th:text=${var.id}`, 
but here I want only 1. How can i get it?.

Can any one please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you send a object list (product list) or a single product? you can only iterate a collection, not a single object. However if you iterate a list  please refer [this iteration status might help you](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status)

Comment: var.id contains 3 values 0,1,2. But i want to print only value 1.

Comment: `var.id` is it a `String` with value `"0,1,2"`, or is it a `integer` field that can be either 0 or 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Why don't you use `th:if="${var.id == 1}" th:text="${var.id}"` ?

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion @nmy. But i think that is not a correct way what you have suggested, because we don't know what will be the second value. I have mentioned 0,1,2 only as a example.

Answer (score 18):

Thymeleaf expressions use SpEL (Spring Expression Language), so you can use all the features available from SpEL. From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-properties-arrays) you can see that contents of a collection/array can be accessed using square brackets.

For example, if `products` is a collection of objects each with an `id` field:

```
<div th:text="${products[1].id}"></div>
```

Then the contents of the `div` would be the value of `id` in the second object. Other elements can be accessed by changing the index between the square brackets.

Comment: Whats the alternative way on doing this, with out the [1] array?

Comment: If the object is an implementation of the generic List<?> type you can use methods like .size() and .get(position) in your template.

Comment: Hyperlink to 'documentation' is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do two things,

> 1) You can use th:if in your div or any other tag. like this.

```
<div th:if="${var.variable == <YourValue>}" 
     th:text="${var.variable}"></div>
```

> 2) or you can just send that single value form your controller, and then just you can use that here.